# How to apply function to a list in incremental manner?

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, apply

Having a list of

```
{a, b, c, d}
```

and a function

```
f
```

I wish to get a list

```
{f[a], f[a,b], f[a,b,c], f[a,b,c,d]}
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f @@@ ({a, b, c, d}[[1 ;; #]] & /@ Range[4])
```

> {f[a], f[a, b], f[a, b, c], f[a, b, c, d]}

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly simple, but it works

```
lst = {a, b, c, d};
Block[{f}, SetAttributes[f, Flat]; FoldList[f, f@First@#, Rest@#]]& @ lst
(* {f[a], f[a, b], f[a, b, c], f[a, b, c, d]} *)
```

This, too, based on my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16571/52) to a very similar [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16556/52):

```
f @@@ FoldList[#1~Join~{#2} &, {First@#}, Rest@#]& @ lst
(* {f[a], f[a, b], f[a, b, c], f[a, b, c, d]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some other formulations:

```
f @@ Take[{a, b, c, d}, #] & ~Array~ 4

f[a, b, c, d] ~Take~ # & ~Array~ 4

Rest @ FoldList[Append, f[], {a, b, c, d}]
```

All but the first may evaluate `f` in an undesired way but you could use `Block` to prevent that.

```
f = Print;

Block[{f},
  f[a, b, c, d] ~Take~ # & ~Array~ 4
]
```

> a
>
> ab
>
> abc
>
> abcd